# Fake CM elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Suppose one has an elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with conductor $N < k^3$ for some (large) positive $k$, with the property that its Fourier coefficients satisfy 
$$
a_p=0, \; \mbox{ for all } \; p \equiv -1 \mod{4}, \; \; \;  k/3 < p < k.
$$
Can one prove unconditionally that $E$ has CM? This follows from work of Serre (under GRH) or Elkies (under something like Szpiro's conjecture), since otherwise we'd have a surplus of supersingular primes. It does not appear to be a consequence of, say, Serre's argument without additional hypotheses (though I'd be happy to be wrong on this score).

Comment: Dear Mike: Can one make "effective" (in the spirit of your question) any information coming from the knowledge that Sato-Tate holds in the non-CM case? (Sorry to answer a question with another question...).

Comment: Dear BCrd : I've pondered that, but I really don't know. My admittedly uneducated guess would be "probably not" with the level of precision I'm after....