# Effective detection of CM modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, computational-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Say $f$ is a newform of weight $k$ and level $\Gamma_1(N)$. $f$ is called CM if, for example, there is an imaginary quadratic field $K$ such that for all $p\nmid N$ which are inert in $K$, the $p$th Fourier coefficient $a_p$ of $f$ is 0. (Ribet's article [*Galois representations attached to eigenforms with Nebentypus*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0063943) is a nice reference for this material). Specific examples include the newforms attached to CM elliptic curves. All examples arise as inductions of algebraic Hecke characters of $K$ of type $(k-1,0)$.

Is there an effective bound in terms of $k$ and $N$ (or other basic invariants of $f$) on how many $a_p$ you have to check to know whether or not $f$ is CM? Or, is there an effective bound on the discriminant of the associated $K$ and the conductor of the associated algebraic Hecke character? What if we assume GRH?

A related question was asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49937) by Mike Bennett, but no answer has been given.

My motivation is simply to be able to computationally check if a given newform is CM using, say, SAGE. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the form itself is completely determined by the first $O(kN^3)$ (or something like that) coefficients...

Comment: Assuming GRH for Rankin-Selberg L-functions allows you to distinguish a modular form from very few terms in its Fourier expansion, on the order of $(\log k q)^2$.  This should be in Chapter 5 of Iwaniec-Kowalski but I don't have the book on hand.

Comment: @Matt Young: Yup, it's there, in section 5.8 (where your $q$ is my $N$). There's an absolute constant $C$ lying around, but maybe if I traced back everything I could explicitly compute it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the form is CM then it will be isomorphic to a quadratic twist of itself. So I think what I'd do with a form which I suspect is or is not CM is to just twist by all the (finitely many ) possible quadratic characters that could be involved and then to check to see if $f$ is the same as its twist, which one can do by proving that the difference is zero using the standard bound (1+degree of $\omega^k$ on the modular curve).

Comment: Re the discriminant and conductor: if $N$ is the level of $f$ and $f$ is new, then $N$ is the product of $|d|$ ($d$ the discriminant of $K$) and the norm of the conductor of the grossencharacter. This just comes from basic facts about conductors of representations (if I got them right!)

Comment: Ah, yes, for some reason I got myself confused looking at the analytic conductors, but it's clear on the Galois side. Thanks! I'll just add that a proof of the standard bound you mention is available in Murty's paper *Congrences between modular forms* available at http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/congr.dvi .

Answer (score 2):

Given a modular form with CM type vanishing behavior of its coefficients $a_p$ (as described in Ribet) it is often not difficult to find a Hecke character whose L-series agrees with those of your given form. Sturm's bound in terms of the weight $k$ and the level $N$ then tells you how many terms you have to consider in order to ensure that the two forms are the same. (See Sturm 1987, On the congruence of modular forms.)

Comment: Sturm's work seems to only check for congruences between modular forms. Am I missing something?

Comment: "Sturm's Bound" seems now to be a general way of saying "the trivial bound coming from algebraic geometry". It's the same in char 0 and char $p$ (with the same proof), and just says "if a section of a degree $d$ line bundle has a zero of order at least $d+1$ somewhere, it's identically zero".

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

What is actually meant by "If the form is CM then it will be isomorphic to a quadratic twist of itself." (K. Buzzard)?

Because if this should really mean (and the rest of the answer sounds like that) that the form is equal to it's twist then I have the impression that this is not correct. If the conductor $M$ of the character $\chi$ divides the level $N$ of $f$, then a coefficient $a_p$ of $f$ with $p \mid M$ might be non-zero according to Ribet's definition. But after the twist this will be $0$.

I think there are also easy counter-examples. For instance take the unique normalized cusp-form for $\Gamma_0(7)$ and character $\left( \frac{-7}{\cdot} \right)$ the Kronecker character. This form is constructed from a hecke character of $Q(\sqrt{-7})$, as far as I can see.
And $a_n = 0$ if $\left( \frac{-7}{n} \right) = -1$. But $a_7 \neq 0$.

What am I missing?

Comment: So, you start with a normalized newform f and then you twist by some $\chi$ and let $f_\chi$ be the associated newform. Then, $f=f_\chi$ for some $\chi$ if $f$ is CM.

Comment: Aha - thanks!
So you mean that if $f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c(n)q^n$, I don't take the form 
\[
  g = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi(n)c(n)q^n
\]
but I write $g$ as $g=f_\chi + g'$, where $f_\chi$ is a newform?
This would make perfect sense, of course.

(But it is a bit confusing that people write in several places things like $f$ has CM if and only if it is equal to a twist of itself.)